# Set up Azure Pipeline for Test Automation Framework

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need assistance in running my test scripts built-in Java platform with selenium webdriver using Eclipse IDE for my repo and used git to push my repo to Azure DevOps. The project is set up in Maven. How do I run my test scripts using pipelines in Azure DevOps?

Comment: Show us the code of what you've tried so far and where you are getting stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure get more details from you. So here just share my suggestion on how to run Selenium tests in the release pipeline for Java application.

---

*In my scenario, I deploy my Java application to **azure web app service** then run it. If you don't want, you can also deploy to local tomcat by using [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.apachetomcat) extension.*

1) After the Java application build, copy the project to the **artifact** of the release during Build pipeline via [copy files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and [publish artifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) task.

[image]

2) Create release pipeline, then add [Azure app service task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops) to deploy my Java application to azure.

3) Add a [Maven](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/maven?view=azure-devops) task to the release pipeline, configure the task to make it point to pom.xml file which located in artifact.

[image]

4) Trigger the Selenium tests in **pom.xml**.

Now you can run browser to view the test.

---

*You can check this [lab blog](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/selenium/) to get more details. Just focus on the design logic of pipeline execution, because the sample in that blog is running with `vstest.exe`.*

Comment: Thank you so much! That is what I needed. I will let you know if I have additional questions.

Comment: @airkhan Hi, friend,. May I know how's the status of this? Does this truly give you the help? If yes, you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. Hope I could hear good news from you:-)

Comment: It will work if my application is on the cloud, but will keep this post open until resolved. Thank you.